# Function OnEdit run slow and timeout error

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp, google-apps-script-triggers

I have a short timestamp script for my google spreadsheet. But it run quite slow and make a lots

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var TIMERECIEVE = [0,-29];
  var DATETRECIEVE = [0,-28];
  var DATEDONE = [0,-25]; 
  var DATECHECK = [0,-2];

var sheets =
  ["OS_PE",
  "OS_EPP1",
  "OS_VE",
  "OS_3D",
  "OS_CP",
  "OS_PA",
  "OS_Test"]
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();1
  for (var s = 0; s < sheets.length; s++) {
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[s]);
    if( sheet.getSheetName() === sheets[s] ) 

    {var selectedCell = ss.getActiveRange();
     {   if( selectedCell.getColumn() == 31) {
       var check1 = selectedCell.offset(TIMERECIEVE[0],TIMERECIEVE[1]);
       var check2 = selectedCell.offset(DATETRECIEVE[0],DATETRECIEVE[1]);
      if(selectedCell.getValue() > 0) 
        {check1.setValue(new Date())
      check2.setValue(new Date());}}}

    {   if( selectedCell.getColumn() == 32){
        var check = selectedCell.offset(DATEDONE[0],DATEDONE[1]);
        if( selectedCell.getValue() >0) 
          check.setValue(new Date());}}

     {  if( selectedCell.getColumn() == 10){
      var check3=selectedCell.offset(DATECHECK[0],DATECHECK[1]);
      if( selectedCell.getValue() === 'App')
        check3.setValue(new Date());}}

     {  if( selectedCell.getColumn() == 11){
      var check4=selectedCell.offset(DATECHECK[0],DATECHECK[1])
      if( selectedCell.getValue() === 'Done')
        check4.setValue(new Date());}}



      }}
  }
```

Comment: *and make a lots*?? Please [edit]

Answer (score 0):

SpreadsheetApp methods are slow so in order to speed-up our script we should minimize the use of them specially whenever it's possible avoid the use of these methods inside of loops.

One thing to try is to get/set all the values with a single calle rather than making multiple calls to the SpreadsheetApp methods by usins `getValues()` instead of `getValue()` and `setValues()` instead of `setValue()`.